# Upgrading from Mac OSX 10.5.8 – Online Download

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade, download

I need to upgrade my osx from 10.5.8 to the latest. After checking the Mac store, it seems like I need 10.6 before can get to 10.8, but I dont have time to get the discs for 10.6. Is there any way to do this online? I looked online but cant find a 10.6 download..

Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the download for upgrading to 10.8 includes a complete installer for the new system. But that would mean to install a new system instead of updating an existing one.

But from what I've seen so far it seems best to install a clean new system as an updated one might behave strange in some parts. Especially in regart to speed a clean install seems to have advantages.

I remember that There are some instructions on how to create a bootable USB drive from the downloaded updater to install the new system. Your favourite search engine will show you some.